# UIView appereance from bottom to top and vice versa(Core Animation)

Tags: ios, xamarin, uiview, xamarin.ios, core-animation

My goal is to understand and implement feature via Core Animation.
I think it's not so hard,but unfortunately i don't know swift/Obj C and it's hard to understand native examples.

---

### Visual implementation

So what exactly i want to do(few steps as shown on images):
1. [image: Source]
2. [image]
3. [image]
4. [image]

And the same steps to hide view(vice versa,from top to bottom) until this :

[image]

Also,i want to make this **UIView** more generic,i mean to put this **UIView** on my StoryBoard and put so constraints on AutoLayout(to support different device screens).

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: The features you want to implement _don't require_ `Core Animation`. It can be done by the simple `UIView animateWithDuration:` APIs. I'll highly _recommend_ reading some tutorials on this topic & try out the implementations first hand. Come up with some code, if its erroneous you can always ask for tweaks around here. :) https://www.raywenderlich.com/2454/uiview-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-uiview-animation

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming the original view is something like:

```
var view = new UIView(new CGRect(View.Frame.Left, View.Frame.Height - 200, View.Frame.Right, 0));
view.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
```

#### Show:

```
UIView.Animate(2.0, 0.0,
    UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear,
    () =>
        {
            view.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;
            var height = 100;
            view.Frame = new CGRect(View.Frame.Left, view.Frame.Y - height , view.Superview.Frame.Right, height);
        },
    () =>
        {
            // anim done
        }                                  
);
```

#### Hide:

```
UIView.Animate(2.0, 0.0,
    UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear,
    () =>
        {
            view.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
            var height = 100;
            view.Frame = new CGRect(View.Frame.Left, view.Frame.Y + height, view.Superview.Frame.Right, 0);

        },
    () =>
        {
            view.Hidden = true;
        }
);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!!!
Exactly what i need and works fine. 
But why when i'm trying to use my own UIView that was created in storyboard,its not working well,i mean its showing full view Height?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuVhy.gif please see this .gif animation. Also,i tried to put parameter "height" as "View.Frame.Height" and it take real Height of view,but won't work :(.

Comment: Also,i have no idea,but constraints on AutoLayout seems that won't work in Xamarin.iOS designer(Storyboards). Do you have same behaviour ? I think ill create a new question about it...

Comment: @VetaLio If you are using constraints via a storyboard/xib, you will not want to animate the `Frame` height, but animate the constraint height. Add an outlet for the height constraint and do something like `this.HeightCon.Constant = 100;` in the animate Action. ref: outlet creation: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/controls/part_1_-_creating_user_interface_objects/

Comment: i have no idea,but i cant write to you via "@" .
So i have tried,but it didn't worked,so tomorrow ill try again. Btw,i will mark your answer as solution asap,but need to fix my problem :).

Comment: @SushiHangover, pls can you help with this on Swift 4

Comment: For Swift5 UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0,
                       delay: 0.0,
                       options: AnimationOptions.curveLinear,
                       animations: {
                        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
                        view.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.minX, y: view.frame.minY - height, width: view.superview!.x, height: height)
        }, completion: ({ _ in
            // Done
        }))

Answer (score 29):

> You can use like this Extension

```
extension UIView{
    func animShow(){
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseIn],
                       animations: {
                        self.center.y -= self.bounds.height
                        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
        self.isHidden = false
    }
    func animHide(){
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 0, options: [.curveLinear],
                       animations: {
                        self.center.y += self.bounds.height
                        self.layoutIfNeeded()

        },  completion: {(_ completed: Bool) -> Void in
        self.isHidden = true
            })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

See my view case was opposite i am directly doing changes in that , test if it is working for you,

**Show Logic**

```
//Add your view on storyBoard / programmatically bellow tab bar

[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.miniMenuView];

CGRect rectformedicationTableViewcell;// = CGRectZero;

rectformedicationTableViewcell = CGRectMake(0.0f, self.view.frame.size.hight, self.view.frame.size.width, 150.0f);

self.miniMenuView.frame = rectformedicationTableViewcell;

if([self.miniMenuView superview]) {
    self.miniMenuView.hidden = YES;
}
self.miniMenuView.hidden = NO;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                 animations:^{
                       [self.miniMenuView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, self.view.frame.size.hight - 150.0f, self.view.frame.size.width, 150.0f)];

                 }
                 completion:nil];
```

**Hide Logic**

```
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:self.miniMenuView];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                 animations:^{

                                                 [self.miniMenuView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, self.view.frame.size.hight, self.view.frame.size.width, 150.0f)];


                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL completed){
                     if([self.miniMenuView superview]) {
                         self.miniMenuView.hidden = YES;
                     }

                 }];
```

Consider this as basic idea do changes as per your requirements Best luck.

Comment: And i think you can do it by doing changes in ViewHeight also. :)

Answer (score 1):

Update answer from @SushiHangover in swift 4.x

Assuming the original view is something like:

```
yourView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 900, width: yourView.frame.width, height:  yourView.frame.height)
```

Show:

```
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.2, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
        let height:CGFloat = 280;
        self.yourView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.yourView.frame.minY - height, width: self.yourView.frame.width, height: self.vBaseView.frame.height)
    }) { finished in
        // animation done
    }
```

Hide
*Just add the height*

```
self.yourView.frame.minY + height
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the issue like https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuVhy.gif commented https://stackoverflow.com/users/4793465/xtl for the above solution.

Am using the view at the bottom of web-view to show and hide like safari mobile browser.

attached the sample code below 
`UIView *viewV;
UILabel *label;`

and viewdidload

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
WKWebViewConfiguration *theConfiguration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
WKWebView *webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame configuration:theConfiguration];
webView.navigationDelegate = self;
webView.UIDelegate = self;
webView.scrollView.delegate = self;
NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com/"];
NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
[webView loadRequest:nsrequest];
[self.view addSubview:webView];

viewV = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 50, self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];
viewV.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[webView addSubview:viewV];}
```

and scroll view delegate

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
CGPoint velocity = [[scrollView panGestureRecognizer] velocityInView:scrollView.superview];
if (velocity.y == 0) {
    return;
}
if (velocity.y < -1) {
    // Scrolling left
    NSLog(@"Top");
    if (viewV.frame.origin.y != self.view.frame.size.height - 50) {// if already hidden, don't need to hide again
        return;
    }
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
        viewV.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        viewV.frame = CGRectMake(0, viewV.frame.origin.y + 50, self.view.frame.size.width, 0);

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
} else if (velocity.y > 1) {
    // Scrolling Right
    NSLog(@"Bottom");
    if (viewV.frame.origin.y != self.view.frame.size.height) { // if already shown, no need to do show again
        return;
    }
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
        viewV.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        viewV.frame = CGRectMake(0, viewV.frame.origin.y - 50, self.view.frame.size.width, 50);

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    }];
}}
```

This worked for me.